# Can't access openproject from outside local

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, openproject

I've installed openproject on ubuntu 22.04.3 with apache2, and i can only access it locally.

apache2/ports.conf:

```
If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also 
have to change the VirtualHost statement in
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 0.0.0.0:80

<IfModule ssl_module>
Listen 443
 </IfModule>

 <IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
Listen 443
 </IfModule>
 vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

apache2/sites-available/openproject.conf:

```
Include /etc/openproject/addons/apache2/includes/server/*.conf IncludeOptional /etc/openproject/addons/apache2/custom/server/*.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName 127.0.1.1
DocumentRoot /opt/openproject/public
ProxyRequests off
Include /etc/openproject/addons/apache2/includes/vhost/*.conf IncludeOptional
/etc/openproject/addons/apache2/custom/vhost/*.conf
# Can't use Location block since it would overshadow all the other proxypass directives on Centos ProxyPass /openproject/ http://127.0.0.1:6000/openproject/ retry=0
ProxyPassReverse /openproject/ http://127.0.0.1:6000/openproject/
</VirtualHost>
```

sudo netstat -tuln | grep 80:

```
tcp  0  0  0.0.0.0:80  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN
```

[image: ufw_stauts]

Comment: I am aware that this does not answer the question but it might be an option to use one of the [installation methods (e.g. package, docker, kubernetes) provided by OpenProject](https://www.openproject.org/docs/installation-and-operations/installation/)